# Problema con rutas de angular

Tags: angular

Requiero ejecutar un proyecto de angular. Uso el comando "npm run start", pero al momento que ya esta ejecutando no me permite acceder a ninguna ruta.

Comparto el proyecto para que me colaboren con una guía para que pueda ejecutar bien el proyecto.

[https://github.com/BosatzuKannon/Cliente](http://https:/https://github.com/BosatzuKannon/Cliente)

Comment: Eso es por que en tu código hay un error que no te deja compilar. Si pones los mensajes que te muestra le terminal y/o el navegador será más fácil ayudarte.

Answer (score 2):

prueba corriendo el proyecto con el cli de esta forma: ng serve --o

y para las rutas parece que usas HREF en angular se suele usar el [routerLink]="['/(TU RUTA VA AQUI PERO DEBE ESTAR DECLARADA EN TU MODULO DE ROUTING)]"

Answer (score 0):

Existe un error en la referencia al archivo **tsconfig.json** en el archivo **tsconfig.app.json**

La ruta relativa debería ser:

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json"
}
```

Te comparto pull request para que veas los cambios que tuve que hacer para levantar la app, ya que habían otros errores:

[Pull Request](https://github.com/BosatzuKannon/Cliente/pull/1)